# Can't read PUT XML request in Grails controller

Tags: grails, groovy, httprequest, grails-controller

I'm trying to parse XML in a Grails controller - I can successfully parse the result of a GET but when receiving a PUT, I can't get the values out of the request. Code follows.

Test: (PUTs a dummy Person so that I can test the parsing and saving)

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin
import org.junit.*
import com.mycompany.stuff.Person

@TestFor(ServiceController)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class ServiceControllerTests {
    void testCreateWithXML() {
        mockDomain(Person)
        request.method = "PUT"
        def controller = new ServiceController()
        controller.request.contentType = 'text/xml'
        controller.request.content = '''
                <person>
                    <refId>123-abc</refId>
                    <otherThing>some stuff</otherThing>
                </person>
                '''.stripIndent().getBytes() // note we need the bytes (copied from docs)
        def response = controller.create()
        assert Person.count() == 1
        assertEquals "123-abc", Person.get("123-abc").id
    }
}
```

Controller: Receives the put (correctly) after being mapped to the create method.

```
class ServiceController {
...
    def create() {
        if (request.format != "xml") {
            render 406 // Only XML expected
            return
        }

        def requestBody = request.XML
        def objectType  = requestBody.name() as String
        log.info "Received ${objectType} - ${requestBody}"
        if (!(objectType.toLowerCase() in ['person','personsubtype']))
        {
                render (status: 400, text: 'Unknown object type received in PUT')
                return
        }

        def person      = new Person(id: requestBody.person.refId.text())
        person.save()

        log.info "Saved ${person}"
        render 200
    }
```

Using the debugger, I can see that when the request is received, the variable requestBody is received as a NodeChild, and the `name()` is correct. I can also see that the `requestBody.person.refId` variable's metaClass is of `GPathResult`... yet the `.text()` (and `.toString()`) always return `null`. The first `log.info` prints the output:

```
2013-07-09 20:04:07,862 [main] INFO  client.ServiceController  - Received person - 123-abcsome stuff
```

so I know that the contents came across.

Any and all suggestions appreciated. I've been trying this for some time and am at my wits' end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `refId` inappropriately from `requestBody`. In your case `<person>` is itself represented by `requestBody`.

`requestBody.refId.text()` will give you `123-abc`.

The controller implementation and the test case should be written this way:

```
def create() {
        if (request.format != "xml") {
            render 406 // Only XML expected
            return
        }

        def requestBody = request.XML
        def objectType  = requestBody.name() as String

        //You can see here objectType is person which signifies
        //requestBody is represented as the parent tag <person> 
        log.info "Received ${objectType} - ${requestBody}"
        if (!(objectType.toLowerCase() in ['person','personsubtype'])) {
            render (status: 400, text: 'Unknown object type received in PUT')
            return
        }

        //Since <person> is represented by requestBody, 
        //refId can be fetched directly from requestBody
        def person = new Person(id: requestBody.refId.text())
        person.save()

        log.info "Saved ${person}"
        render 200
    }
```

Test Class can be optimized and unwanted items can be removed:-

```
//Test Class can be optimized
import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*
import com.mycompany.stuff.Person

@TestFor(ServiceController)
//@Mock annotation does the mocking for domain classes
@Mock(Person)
class ServiceControllerTests {
    void testCreateWithXML() {
        //mockDomain(Person) //Not required, taken care by @Mock
        request.method = "PUT"
        //No need to initialize controller 
        //as @TestFor will provide controller.
        //def controller = new ServiceController()
        controller.request.contentType = 'text/xml'
        controller.request.content = '''
                <person>
                    <refId>123-abc</refId>
                    <otherThing>some stuff</otherThing>
                </person>
                '''.stripIndent().getBytes() // note we need the bytes (copied from docs)
        controller.create()

        assert controller.response.contentAsString == 200
        assert Person.count() == 1
        assertEquals "123-abc", Person.get("123-abc").id
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmahapatro, thank you very much for the fantastic answer. The test content feeds through now.